# Rails Active Record model lifecycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Active Record model method that's basically just a database query, and I'd like to cache the results, ideally as simply as as via a local variable in the model:

```
my_data = method_already_called ? stored_results : do_query
```

This made me realise that I don't really understand the object lifecycle of an Active Record model, and all the Rails guides really tell you is about callbacks. Specifically, I can guess that the object will be created when the user wants to retrieve some data associated with that object, but I have no idea when that object is going to be destroyed.

At a practical level, say a user requests some information, which causes an AR object to be created, take some instance data from the DB and manipulate it before presenting it to the user. How long does that object hang around in memory if the user wants to instruct it to do something based upon that information?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm specifically interested in the behaviour of Rails 5.1 on Ruby 2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, as long as you keep a reference to this instance. In most cases - until a request is finished.

```
class Model
  # most common memoization pattern
  def something
    @cached_result ||= do_query
  end
end
```

So, when your model will be instantiated (in controller/service/etc), it will be available as long as you can reference it. On the next request, `@cached_result` will be re-calculated.
If you want to cache something between requests, you can use CacheStore:

```
class Model
  def something
    Rails.cache.fetch("cache_key") do
      do_query
    end
  end
end
```

Do not treat cache as permanent store though. But this will allow you to cache something between requests and for some period of time.

btw, @cached_result will be calculated for each model instance. If you do something like `Model.where(field: "value")` that returns 2+ instances, each of them will do `do_query` on the first call.